# How to share artifacts between gitlab-runner jobs, without exposing them for download?

Tags: .net, gitlab-ci

I am working on a .NET configuration file for a WPF C# project.  My build_job creates dlls, that my test_job needs to access.  Currently I've been doing something like this:

```
build_job:
  stage: build
  only:
    - tags  
  script:
    - '"%NUGET_PATH%" restore'
    - '"%MSBUILD_PATH%" /p:Configuration=Release'
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - "%RELEASE_FOLDER%AutoBuildWpfTest.exe"
      - "%RELEASE_FOLDER%NLog.config"
      - "%RELEASE_FOLDER%NLog.dll"
      - "%TEST_FOLDER%Tests.dll"

test_job:
  stage: test
  only:
    - tags
  script:

    - '"%NUNIT_RUNNER_PATH%" %TEST_FOLDER%Tests.dll'
  dependencies:
    - build_job
```

The problem with this approach is that my artifacts.zip file is now polluted with files that were only needed for testing, but are not required for actual deployment.

My question is how can I share the files between jobs without them showing up in artifacts.zip?

Also, is there any way to add files to artifacts.zip without preserving the directory tree?  When building .NET projects you end up with some pretty deep directories, for example my output executables are in:

AutoBuildWpfTest\bin\Release\

, so when they get zipped up, and you try to open them, you have to go through 4 folder levels to get to the file you want.  Ideally, I'd want all my output files, right in the root of artifact.zip. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I see out of this would be to get the artifacts from the test stage so maybe your .yml would look like this:

```
build_job:
  stage: build
  only:
    - tags  
  script:
    - '"%NUGET_PATH%" restore'
    - '"%MSBUILD_PATH%" /p:Configuration=Release'
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - "%RELEASE_FOLDER%AutoBuildWpfTest.exe"
      - "%RELEASE_FOLDER%NLog.config"
      - "%RELEASE_FOLDER%NLog.dll"
      - "%TEST_FOLDER%Tests.dll"

test_job:
  stage: test
  only:
    - tags
  script:

    - '"%NUNIT_RUNNER_PATH%" %TEST_FOLDER%Tests.dll'
    - mv %RELEASE_FOLDER%AutoBuildWpfTest.exe AutoBuildWpfTest.exe 
    - mv %RELEASE_FOLDER%NLog.config NLog.config
    - mv %RELEASE_FOLDER%NLog.dll NLog.dll

  dependencies:
    - build_job
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - "AutoBuildWpfTest.exe"
      - "NLog.config"
      - "NLog.dll"
```

Then you could download the artifacts from **test_job**. I know it is not ideal but the documentation doesn't show any advanced ways of dealing with individual artifacts. Also moving the files should eliminate the other problem with nested folders. I know it is also not ideal but its the only way I've found to be effective

Comment: Not sure about the mv syntax please correct me if I'm wrong. It has been almost a year since I've done any dev work on windows let alone powershell

Comment: Are those files guaranteed to still be there during test_job, after build_job has already completed?

Comment: Yes they are guaranteed to be there because the test_job should download all the artifacts from the build_job since you have listed build_job as a dependency. Gitlab has no way of knowing which artifacts you want in the test job so it passes on everything. And it looks to me like the build_job has to run first so the files should always be there.

Comment: From your example, I still see you're adding Tests.dll to the artifacts in build_job, so I will still end up with it in zip file?  Also you compose another set of artifacts in test_job, that's identical to build_job, except for test_dll.

Comment: I'm saying you should use artifacts from test_job not build_job as shown above in bold because they'll not only be identical but only have the release artifacts and without having an extra folder in the generated zip if you manually move the release files

Comment: So you're essentially saying I will have two sets of zip downloads on the site?

Comment: Yes there is no other way to do this, you could set a shorter expiry for the first set of artifacts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155590/discussion-between-clive-makamara-and-eternal21).